# How to print or access to data in a list in class?

Tags: python, list

How can I print or return a list that is in a `class`? How can I access to members of that `list`? **(in the class and out of the class)**

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.students = []
        self.list = []
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def add(self, element):
        self.list.append(element)
        self.students.append(self.list)

while True:
    option = input("Choose an option: \n1. add")
    if option == "1":
        obj = Manager(input("Username: "), input("Password: "))
        obj.add(obj)
        print("Username: " + str(obj.username), "\nPassword: " + str(obj.password))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: From your example code it's unclear what list you'd want to access? However, there's a number of issues with the example code: you need to indent the methods in the class. You shouldn't name an attribute `list` since it will shadow the keyword `list`. You probably don't want to append the entire list `self.list` to `self.students` every time you're trying to add a list (that's what the current code is doing).

Comment: I didn't write the entire code. I will make an object of this class that contains a username and password in a loop. Then i append that object to list and then i will append the list to a bigger list called Students.

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
test = Manager("a", "b" )
test.add("hey")

print(test.list)
```

You should not do

```
obj.add(obj)
```

Comment: I tried it at first but i saw something like that: [<__main__.Manager object at 0x00000200>]

Comment: if you do `print([obj])` you will see the same thing. Don't place the object inside itself with `obj.add(obj)`. The argument `self` is given by default, you should give the argument `element`.

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```py
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def add(self, element):
        self.list.append(element)
    
    def print_nth_element(self, n):
        print(self.list[n])
    
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.list)
    
manager = Manager()
manager.add("Eric")
manager.add("John")

print("***Access from inside the class***")
manager.print_nth_element(n=0)
manager.print_nth_element(n=1)
manager.print_list()

print("***Access from outside the class***")
print(manager.list[0])
print(manager.list[1])
print(manager.list)
```

Output:

```
***Access from inside the class***
Eric
John
['Eric', 'John']
***Access from outside the class***
Eric
John
['Eric', 'John']
```

Comment: Now i wrote the entire code in the box

Comment: @M2. see my updated example: is this what you were looking for? (If not, please could you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve?)

Comment: Please look again at my code. When I want to execute print(obj.list[0]), I see <__main__.Manager object at 0x00000284D22>

Comment: If you look at my code, I think I answered the original question, which was "How can I print or return a list that is in a class? How can I access to members of that list? (in the class and out of the class)". The reason you are seeing this result of the print statement is because of other issues with your code. Firstly, in the line `obj = Manager(input("Username: "), input("Password: "))`, you create a new `Manager` object in every iteration of the loop (and the previous object is discarded); this means that when the loop finishes, you only have the last username and password that were added

Comment: Secondly, in the line `obj.add(obj)`, the value of `obj` is the `Manager` object you created in the previous line. So when you call the `add` method, you are adding this `Manager` object to `self.list` and `self.students`. So `self.list` contains only `Manager` objects, and this explains why you see `<__main__.Manager object at 0x00000284D22>` when you call `print(obj.list[0])`

Comment: If these comments and my answer above don't help you solve your problem, you probably need to edit the question so it's more clear what you're actually trying to achieve